# Is there a way to see the response to Twilio's request to the SMS URL?

Tags: twilio

When I set my SMS Url for a given phone number and then send a text to that phone number, the request somehow fails.  Is there a way for me to inspect the error response (404/500/403 etc) to see any exception details from my twilio dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Twilio Customer Support here,

Have you viewed the app monitor?

https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/app-monitor

It contains all of the errors that your account has recorded, you can drill down on each error to see the request body etc.